# create SEO friendly URL using rewriterule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I try to rewrite my SEO URLs to some real GET requests, to handle in my PHP file.

I want to have these 2 cases to work:

```
mysite.com/company-profile -> index.php?action=company-profile

mysite.com/faq/howcanijoin -> index.php?action=faq&anchor=howcanijoin
```

I got the first case to work using the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$   index.php?action=$1
```

For the second I tried also. I put this rule before the previous one:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$   index.php?action=$1&anchor=$2
```

But it's not working. Any suggestions? If I understand correctly inside each parenthesis goes variables `$1, $2` etc?

Comment: There are so many examples, frameworks, etc. that have this already worked out for you. Why do it yourself? If you need a lightweight router, checkout the Slim framework.

Comment: Leave the variable parsing to your PHP script, you normally only need one rewrite at all. And please see the thousands of duplicates here on the website. Yes much to digg through but this is practically asked on a daily basis.

Comment: @hakre PHP parsing is more advisable than using .htaccess?

Comment: @hakre, are you talking about everything (but maybe physical files or whatnot) gets routed through `/index.php` by passing `/index.php/seo/please/help`? I was thinking this was how the Symfony router worked.

Comment: Yes exactly, has the benefit that you can do any kind of rewrites in your own code, not inside server configuration.

Comment: Here's Slim's `.htaccess` and `index.php`: https://github.com/codeguy/Slim Pretty "slim".

Comment: guys I know there are many examples here which I read. I am sure I am missing something small.

Comment: @hakre is it possible to do this just with php? from the format of my path, i.e mysite.com/faq/howcanijoin, I will need a different file for each path. I want everything to get routed though ./index.php

Comment: Sure this [is possible](https://gist.github.com/hakre/5116347) otherwise I would have not suggested that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1&anchor=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=$1&anchor=$2 [QSA,L]
```